# What is the plot of this integral?

Tags: integration

$$y=\int_{x-1}^{x+1}\sqrt{1+4t^2}dt;$$

I put it into wolfram alpha, but nothing came up.

It's supposed to graph to length between two points that are 2 units away from eachother on the x axis, with the x axis being on a y=x^2 graph

Comment: Intresting, how or what made you think of this?

Answer (score 1):

Since
$$
\int \sqrt{1+4t^2}\,dt = \frac{1}{2}t\sqrt{1+4t^2}+\frac{1}{4}\text{arsinh}\,(2t),
$$
your $y$ equals
$$
\begin{aligned}
y&=\frac{1}{2}(x+1)\sqrt{1+4(x+1)^2}+\frac{1}{4}\text{arsinh}\,(2(x+1))\\
&\qquad-
\frac{1}{2}(x-1)\sqrt{1+4(x-1)^2}+\frac{1}{4}\text{arsinh}\,(2(x-1)).
\end{aligned}
$$
A graph is attached below.

[image: plot of distance of $x+1$ and $x-1$ on $y=x^2$]

Comment: WOW! Thank you so much!  How did you get that answer, anyway?

Comment: The primitive function is calculated (many times?) on this site. If that is what you meant? The way to go is to integrate by parts.